# Do we need to perform sajdah if we hear the recitation of certain ayat but don't listen attentively?

Tags: quran-recitation, sajda

We know that we have to sajdah (prostration) after reciting some ayats (verses) in the holy Qur'an. If anyone hear the recitation then he also have to sajdah.

My question is: Is it necessary to perform sajdah if we don't listen to the recitation attentively?

Comment: To do a sajda (some scholars say) you must have wudu, then under some conditions you don't even have to perform it for example if you are learning/memorizing the Quran (doing it at most 1 time would be sufficient), then the madhabs have differences about whether it is sunnah or fard/farz see also http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25529/number-of-sajdas-in-quran-in-every-para

Answer (score 2):

**As far as I know, the narrations have not mentioned regarding its necessarily to Sajdah just if you hear it attentively. Actually there must not be any difference between hearing or reciting it attentively or carelessly.**
According to the fatwas of religious scholars (Maraje’ of Taqlid) it is mandatory for people to Sajdah if they hear or recite any of those verses.

---

**Imam Khomeini:**

> There is a verse in each of the following Surahs that everyone who
>   hears or recites them, (when the verse finished), he or she must
>   Sajdah. And if forgot, then ought to Sajdah once he or she remembers.
>   [1](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa1060)

Those verses are available in the following Surahs: **(Sajdah, Foselat, Najm, Alaq)**

---

According to some Marajeul-Taqlid (of Shi'a):

> even if someone listens to the mentioned verses (unwanted), or
>   actually these verses move towards his ears(without his intention), he
>   ought to Sajdah in accordance with the Ehtiat-al-Waajeb (obligatory
>   caution) [2]

To see the detailed text, refer to the source below.

[1](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa1060) توضیح المسائل (المحشى للإمام الخمینی)، ج‏1، ص: 592، مسأله 1093.

(Tozihul-Masaa’el (Al-Mhshi LeEmam Al-Khomaini). Vol.1, Pg592, Mas’alah1093)

[2] آیت الله مکارم شیرازی و آیت الله شبیری زنجانی  (Ayatollah Makarem Shirazi and Shobeiri Zanjani)

---

**Source:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa1060)