# Number of Prostrations in Quran in every Juz (1/30th part of Quran)?

Tags: quran, sajda, sajdat-al-tilaawah

How are there 14 sajdas (prostrations) distributed among the 30 [Juz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juz%27). Which Juz has how many sajdas? How many are up to Juz 13? is it 15 or 14? some places show they are 15.

Comment: What is a para?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many sajdas are in Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/how-many-sajdas-are-in-quran)

Answer (score 4):

The question how much sajdas or sajdat there are is different according to the Madhabs about the number and the terms! But most of the Madhabs say it is sunna and not a fard (farz).

Insha-Allah i will give at first an Answer about the terms of each of the sunni madhabs, then the number of sajadat they count and at least tell you the locations of all theses sajdat to be found according the suras or suwar and the 30 Parts (Ajza' أجزاء plural of juz' جزء) of the Quran. And there i will point if it is not a sajda for a certain Madhab!

Here is an abstract of what i found in the "[Al Majmu'](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=2081&bk_no=14&flag=1)" (المجموع شرح المهذب) of Imam an-Nawawi

- Hanafiya say it's a fard (farz) for the reciter and the listener and
  they count 14 sajda and they canceled the 2nd sajda in Surat al-Hajj and added the one of surat saad.
- Malikya say it's a sunna for both reciter and listener and they count 11 sajda (main line of the Madhab), but Malik also had a 2nd statement saying it's 14 (without the sajda in surat saad).

---

Note: As somebody who knows the (practiced) Maliki view I disagree here with Imam an-Nawawi as i know the Malikiya didn't count the 2nd sajda in surat al-Hajj but they counted the sajda in surat sad. SO what an-Nawawi said  might be an uncommon statement of Imam Malik which has only been narrated by a few of his students and therefore isn't accepted by the majority of the scholars of the madhab!

---

- A-Shafi'ya say it's a sunna and counted 14 sajda and exclude the sajda in surat sad!
- Hanabila say it's a sunna Imam Ahmad had like Imam Malik two statements: 14 as the Shafi'ya and Malik in his 2nd Statement and 15 including both the 2nd sajda in surat al Hajj and the sajda of Surat Sad.

By the way a-Shafiya stated the sajda of surat Sad to be a sujud shukr therefore they didn't count it as a sajda for recitation!

Therefore in the sum there are 15 sajdas!

Now here are the Locations of the sajdas according the order of the Mushaf المصحف:

1. In surat al-A'raaf سورة الأعراف [7:206] [2](http://legacy.quran.com/7/206) (the last Verse of the Sura). 
   This verse is to be found in the 9th juz' (Part) of the Quran!
2. In surat ar-Ra'd سورة الرعد [13:15](http://legacy.quran.com/13/15).
   This Verse is to be found in the 13th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
3. In surat an-Nahl سورة النحل  (The "reason" or "context" for the sajda begins in the Verse 49 and it's accomplished at the end of Verse 50, so if you recite you should recite them both!) [16:49-50](http://legacy.quran.com/16/49-50). 
   This Verse is to be found in the 14th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
4. In surat al-Isra' سورة الإسراء  (at the end of the sura) 107-109 (see my comment on 3.) [17:107-109](http://legacy.quran.com/17/107-109). 
   This Verse is to be found at the beginning of the 15th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
5. In surat Maryam سورة مريم [19:58](http://legacy.quran.com/19/58).
   This Verse is to be found in the 16th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
6. In surat al-Hajj سورة الحج [22:18](http://legacy.quran.com/22/18).
7. Again in surat al-Hajj  سورة الحج [22:77](http://legacy.quran.com/22/77)
   .
   This is the 2nd sajda of surat al Hajj which is **not counted** as a sajda by the Hanafi and Maliki madhab (Imam an-Nawawi says they counted it!).

Both of the sajdas from surat al Hajj are in the 17th juz' (Part) of the Quran.

8. In Surat al-Furqan سورة الفرقان [25:60](http://legacy.quran.com/25/60)
   .
   This Verse is to be found in the 19th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
9. In surat an-Naml سورة النمل (see my comment on 3.) [27:25-26](http://legacy.quran.com/27/25-26)
   .
   This Verse is to be found in the 19th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
10. In surat as-Sajda سورة السجدة [32:15](http://legacy.quran.com/32/15)
    .
    This Verse is to be found in the 21st Juz' (Part) of the Quran
11. In surat Saad سورة ص [38:24](http://legacy.quran.com/38/24)
    .
    This sajda has been **excluded**/not counted by Shafi'ya, Malikiya (according to Imam an-Nawawi) and in one statement of Imam Ahmad.

    This Verse is to be found in the 23rd Juz' (Part) of the Quran
12. In surat Fussilat  سورة فصلت (see my comment on 3.) [41:37-38](http://legacy.quran.com/41/37-38)
    .
    This Verse is to be found in the 24th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
13. In surat a-Najm  سورة النجم [53:62](http://legacy.quran.com/53/62)
    .
    This Verse is to be found in the 27th Juz' (Part) of the Quran
14. In surat al-Inshiqaq  سورة الإنشقاق [84:21](http://legacy.quran.com/84/21)
15. In surat al-Alaq سورة العلق [96:19](http://legacy.quran.com/96/19)

The last **two** sajdas can be found in the 30th juz' (Part) of the Quran.
The last **three** sajdas have been **excluded**/not counted by the Malikya according to one statement of Imam Malik (and this is the the practice of the madhab).

And Allah knows best!

Comment: Hey you need not quote all of the verses here, you just had to copy paste the verse numbers from this [page](http://corpus.quran.com/documentation/versemarks.jsp) and present the link. But, its OK if you did it.

Answer (score 1):

Sajdas (plural in rabic are sujoud) exist in some AYAT where god talk about soujoud like in ayat ANAHL/49 "And for God Prostrate What in heaven and on earth.."
When we say them in salah or while we are reading Quran we do Sujud. Note that this is not mandatory but it preferred to do it beacuse there is THAWAB in doing it
for example the prophet says : "If moslim do sujda devil crys, he says god ask him to do sujda so he did and he will have heavens and god asked me to do sujda and I say no so I will be in hell " 
In ayat soujoud there is some difference in there numbers and AYAT
First all moslims agree on 13 of them

 1/ AlARAF 206

 2/ Arrad 15

 3/ ANAHL 49

 4/ AlIsra 107

 5/ Mariem 58

 6/ AlHaj 18

 7/ Alnaml 25

 8/ ASAJDA 15

 9/ AlForkan 60

 10/ FOUSILAT 38

 13/ ANAJM 62

 14/ AlInchikak 21

 15/ AlAlak 19

For AYAT where there is different opinion

 11/ AlHaj 77

 12/ SAd 25